# Why "too broad"?

Tags: discussion

[Is there a difference between meaning of word позаяк vs. так як?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/43/4)

I think, the questions like:

> are X and Y fully identical, or have some differences?

— are quite rational and answerable. They assume “if, yes, provide at least some examples to prove it” rather then “provide me full, exhaustive and comprehensive list of differences between X and Y”, per my opinion.

Does the community have different opinion? Please explain why.

Comment: I may understand if such question would be closed because "too easy, dictionary question, no research effort" rather than "too broad", but…

Answer (score 4):

The question would be improved if the asker stated the context: “In the following sentence, does the meaning change if the word позаяк is replaced by так як?”

But “позаяк is a (near-)synonym of так як. What nuances are there between the two words?” is also an acceptable question. Unless they are extremely common words with multiple meanings (e.g. prepositions), this is ok. It may or may not be a great question, it depends how much information can be found in dictionaries. Dictionaries are generally good at giving the general meaning, but poor at expressing fine nuances. Bilingual dictionaries are especially bad at distinguishing near-synonyms, so questions of this form are pretty common coming from non-natives who aren't very fluent.

(Background: I don't speak Ukrainian, but I'm a regular and moderator of French Language Stack Exchange.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I consider “In the following sentence, does the meaning change if the word позаяк is replaced by так як?” as possible, but *not mandatory* improvement. I consider questions requiring analysis of *all* possible meanings of the two words being compared as *ok* — unless the words being compared have *too many* meanings (which isn't true in our case). If I understood you correctly, we agree in that. Still, I'd like to hear those who voted for closing the question.